# Sort contents of input file and writing output file

Tags: perl, sorting, file-io

I want to sort the contents of a text file and save it as another text file (or overwrite the previous one). I'm not particularly good with perl so I can't seem to figure out why this code snippet does not work.

```
open(my $file, '>', $filename) or die $!;
print $file $string;

my @curOrd = qw( USD AUD BRL GBP CAD CNY DKK HKD INR IDR ILS JPY MXN NOK 
PHP PLN SGD SKK ZAR KRW SEK CHF TWD THB EUR MYR NZD SAR TRY RUB CZK AED CLP 
EGP MAD NGN OMR QAR );

my $curKnt = scalar @curOrd;
my $outfile = 'file1.txt';
my $infile = 'file2.txt';
open (OUTFILE, ">$outfile");

   foreach my $i (0..$curKnt) {
   open (INFILE, $infile);
   while(<INFILE>)
   {
        my @x= split(',', $_);
        print "x2 = $x[2]\n";
        print "cur_ord = $curOrd[$i]\n";
        if ($x[2] eq $curOrd[$i])  {
           print OUTFILE "$_";
        }
       @x=();
   }  # end of while

   close (INFILE);   

}  # end of foreach

close (OUTFILE);
```

The code is supposed to sort each row while keeping the same format. When I run it, however, I get no errors but the output file is nowhere to be found.

inputfile:

```
20181231,USD,AED,3.6736
20181231,USD,AUD,1.4179
20181231,USD,BRL,3.8817
20181231,USD,CAD,1.3632
20181231,USD,CHF,0.9842
20181231,USD,CLP,694.7432
20181231,USD,CNY,6.8787
20181231,USD,CZK,22.4985
20181231,USD,DKK,6.5252
20181231,USD,EGP,17.9426
20181231,USD,EUR,0.8738
20181231,USD,GBP,0.7853
20181231,USD,HKD,7.8322
20181231,USD,IDR,14483.0392
20181231,USD,ILS,3.7554
20181231,USD,INR,69.5662
20181231,USD,JPY,110.0258
20181231,USD,KRW,1114.7559
20181231,USD,MAD,9.6044
20181231,USD,MXN,19.6584
20181231,USD,MYR,4.1383
20181231,USD,NGN,365.4984
20181231,USD,NOK,8.6848
20181231,USD,NZD,1.4902
20181231,USD,OMR,0.3858
20181231,USD,PHP,52.5907
20181231,USD,PLN,3.7581
20181231,USD,QAR,3.6734
20181231,USD,RUB,69.5418
20181231,USD,SAR,3.7533
20181231,USD,SEK,8.9336
20181231,USD,SGD,1.3637
20181231,USD,SKK,26.3251
20181231,USD,THB,32.4579
20181231,USD,TRY,5.2938
20181231,USD,TWD,30.6034
20181231,USD,USD,1.0000
20181231,USD,ZAR,14.4104
```

Outputfile:

```
20181231,USD,USD,1.0000
20181231,USD,AUD,1.4220
20181231,USD,BRL,3.8828
20181231,USD,GBP,0.7880
20181231,USD,CAD,1.3643
20181231,USD,CNY,6.8782
20181231,USD,DKK,6.5295
20181231,USD,HKD,7.8316
20181231,USD,INR,69.7304
20181231,USD,IDR,14565.1115
20181231,USD,ILS,3.7693
20181231,USD,JPY,110.3364
20181231,USD,MXN,19.6687
20181231,USD,NOK,8.7288
20181231,USD,PHP,52.7242
20181231,USD,PLN,3.7660
20181231,USD,SGD,1.3674
20181231,USD,SKK,26.3387
20181231,USD,ZAR,14.4448
20181231,USD,KRW,1117.0950
20181231,USD,SEK,8.9869
20181231,USD,CHF,0.9846
20181231,USD,TWD,30.6213
20181231,USD,THB,32.6870
20181231,USD,EUR,0.8743
20181231,USD,MYR,4.1555
20181231,USD,NZD,1.4927
20181231,USD,SAR,3.7565
20181231,USD,TRY,5.2892
20181231,USD,RUB,69.4108
20181231,USD,CZK,22.5409
20181231,USD,AED,3.6728
20181231,USD,CLP,694.7031
20181231,USD,EGP,17.9262
20181231,USD,MAD,9.5636
20181231,USD,NGN,365.4074
20181231,USD,OMR,0.3860
20181231,USD,QAR,3.6423
```

Comment: It's best to start all perl scripts with `use autodie qw(:all)` as you don't have to keep writing "or die: $!" even time you open a filehandle.

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: @Andrey just shy of 1kb

Comment: In the first line of this code, you have an example of opening a file following all the current best practices (lexical filehandle, three-arg `open()`, checking the return value and `die()`ing if it fails). But when you come to the actual files you use, you go back to bareword filehandles and two-arg `open()` and you don't check the return value from `open()`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

This works as expected when I test it. I can only suggest that there are some local problems that prevent you from either opening and writing to the output file. You'd see what that problem is if you checked the return value from `open()` and took appropriate action.

I've taken the liberty of tightening up some of your code:

```
my @curOrd = qw( USD AUD BRL GBP CAD CNY DKK HKD INR IDR ILS JPY MXN NOK
                 PHP PLN SGD SKK ZAR KRW SEK CHF TWD THB EUR MYR NZD SAR
                 TRY RUB CZK AED CLP EGP MAD NGN OMR QAR );

my $outfile = 'file1.txt';
my $infile = 'file2.txt';
open (my $out_fh, '>', $outfile)
  or die "Cannot open $outfile: $!";

# Iterating over the values in a list is usually
# better than iterating over the indexes.
foreach my $cur (@curOrd) {
  open ($in_fh, '<', $infile)
    or die "Cannot open $infile: $!";

  while(<$in_fh>) {
    my @x = split(/,/);
    print "x2 = $x[2]\n";
    print "cur_ord = $cur\n";

    if ($x[2] eq $cur)  {
      print $out_fh $_;
    }
  }  # end of while

  close ($in_fh);
}  # end of foreach

close ($out_fh);
```

**Update:** Opening and closing your input file so many times is very inefficient. This version opens it once, splits the data into a two-dimensional array and then sorts that.

```
my @curOrd = qw( USD AUD BRL GBP CAD CNY DKK HKD INR IDR ILS JPY MXN NOK
                 PHP PLN SGD SKK ZAR KRW SEK CHF TWD THB EUR MYR NZD SAR 
                 TRY RUB CZK AED CLP EGP MAD NGN OMR QAR );

# Build a look-up table mapping currencies to their
# sort position
my $i = 0;
my %cur_lookup = map { $_ => $i++ } @curOrd;

my $outfile = 'file1.txt';
my $infile = 'file2.txt';
open (my $out_fh, '>', $outfile)
  or die "Cannot open $outfile: $!";

open(my $in_fh, '<', $infile)
  or die "Cannot open $infile: $!";

my @in_data = map { [ split /,/ ] } <$in_fh>;

print $out_fh
  map { join ',', @$_ }
  sort { $cur_lookup{$a->[2]} <=> $cur_lookup{$b->[2]} } @in_data;

close ($in_fh);
close ($out_fh);
```

Comment: Ok so first of all, thanks for such a detailed explanation and revision. This solves the problem of the file not writing correctly, however, the output file has no information in it

Comment: @PhilipAnkrah: Which version are you using? They both work fine for me, given your input data.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code does not work is because yare trying to read the value of array that is out of range. The script dies at that point.
To fix it add line $curKnt--;

```
my $curKnt = scalar @curOrd;
$curKnt--;
```

Another issue with your script, it opens and closes $infile 30+ times, which is not a good idea. I think you should rewrite your code to read $infile once into array or hash and then process that array or hash. I would write it this way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @curOrd = qw( USD AUD BRL GBP CAD CNY DKK HKD INR IDR ILS JPY MXN NOK PHP PLN SGD SKK ZAR KRW SEK CHF TWD THB EUR MYR NZD SAR TRY RUB CZK AED CLP EGP MAD NGN OMR QAR );

my %data;
my $infile  = 'file2.txt';
my $outfile = 'file1.txt';

open (my $in, "<", $infile) || die "can't open $infile file"; 
while (my $line = <$in>) {
    push(@{$data{(split ',', $line)[2]}}, $line);
}
close $in;

open (my $out, ">", $outfile) || die "can't open $outfile file"; 
foreach my $curr (@curOrd) {
    foreach my $line (@{$data{$curr}}) {
        print $out $line;
    }
}
close $out;
```

Comment: Trying to read beyond the end of an array does not kill the program.

Comment: It seems to die on Windows. The script termintates with the error Perl Command Line Interpreter stopped working ... Which prevents the out file to be written.

Comment: I'm afraid I know next to nothing about running Perl on Windows. But whatever is causing that, it's not from trying to read beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Maybe not, however $curKnt--; does fix it.