# Output file is blank

Tags: perl

I don't know why the following code outputs a blank file. I am running Windows 8. I've received help from this community for previous perl help and this is just what I've been able to put together with the help I've received. However, I can't figure out where this script goes awry.

```
#! perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::FormatText;
use LWP::Simple;

my $dateField = 'date=2018-12-31';
my $currency  = "USD";
my $filename = 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\doc3.txt';
my $address = "https://www.oanda.com/rates/api/v1/rates/$currency.csv?api_key=gpolonsky&decimal_places=4&$dateField&fields=averages&quote=USD&quote=AUD&quote=BRL&quote=CAD&quote=GBP&quote=CHF&quote=CNY&quote=DKK&quote=HKD&quote=INR&quote=IDR&quote=ILS&quote=JPY&quote=MXN&quote=NOK&quote=PHP&quote=PLN&quote=SGD&quote=sKK&quote=ZAR&quote=KRW&quote=SEK&quote=TWD&quote=THB&quote=EUR&quote=MYR&quote=NZD&quote=SAR&quote=TRY&quote=RUB&quote=CZK&quote=AED&quote=CLP&quote=EGP&quote=MAD&quote=NGN&quote=OMR&quote=QAR";
my $content = get($address);
my $s = 1;

defined $content or die "Cannot read '$address': $!";
$content =~  s/^[^\n]*\n//s; 
$content =~  s/^/20181231,/gm; # The m option makes ^ match at the start of each line
$content =~  s/,2018-12-3[0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\+0000*//g;
$content =~  s/([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]),[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/$1/g;

my $string = HTML::FormatText->format_string(
    $content,
    leftmargin  =>  0,
    rightmargin => 23,
);

open(my $file, '>', $filename) or die $!;
print $file $string;

my @curOrd = qw( USD AUD BRL GBP CAD CNY DKK HKD INR IDR ILS JPY MXN NOK PHP PLN SGD SKK ZAR KRW SEK CHF TWD THB EUR MYR NZD SAR TRY RUB CZK AED CLP EGP MAD NGN OMR QAR );
my %data;
my $infile = 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\doc3.txt';
my $outfile = 'file2.txt';

open (my $in, "<", $infile ) || die "can't open $infile file"; 
while (my $line = <$in>) {
    push(@{$data{(split ',', $line)[2]}}, $line);
} 
print $infile;
close $in;

open (my $out, ">", $outfile) || die "can't open $outfile file"; 
foreach my $curr (@curOrd) {
    foreach my $line (@{$data{$curr}}) {
        print $out $line;
    }
}
close $out;
```

Comment: If the output file is blank, which file do you mean? THe file opened by `$filename` or the file opened by `$outfile`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to download data off an API, and that the format you receive the data in is CSV. While LWP::Simple is not my first choice, it should do the trick for you. However, I think I'd use Text::CSV rather than doing some homebrew parsing that I will have to read two more times to wrap my head around.

Comment: @Corion the data that is supposed to be written in $outfile is missing when I go to open the file

Comment: Then the next step is to output the progress as you are writing to `$out`. Print each `$curr` to the screen, and also add `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%data;` to your code to see what content you have in `%data` at all.

Comment: @Corion the output i get is $VAR1 = {};

Comment: @simbabque I will try using Text:CSV

Comment: If you get `$VAR1 = {}`, that means that `%data` was never filled with data, which means that `$in` does not contain any data. Maybe debug this by printing the lines from `$in` as you read them in your program.

Comment: Are you sure that `$data{$curr}` has data?  When you read from `$in` and `split` the line does the third field actually have those fixed currencies from `@curOrd` (which is how you index `%data` when printing to `$out`)?

Comment: @zdim I know the data is there as the output for doc3.txt is accurate and in the desired format. However everything goes away when I try to sort.

Comment: is there a way to directly just add the $string into the array and sort it? @simbabque

Comment: In your program, there is no call to `sort`, so where are you trying to sort anything? If `@curOrd` describes the order of currencies, then most likely your data is not there even before you try to write it. If the output of `print Dumper \%data` shows `$VAR1 = {}`, then you didn't read in any data.

Comment: I actually figured it out @Corion

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer for future visitors to this question.

Comment: @Corion: *where are you trying to sort anything?* It's a weird kind of sorting, but by iterating over `@curOrd` and print the bit of `%data` which matches each currency in turn, he prints the rates in the order he wants them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to explicitly `close()` the file you're writing to before you can re-open it to read from it.

But that whole intermediate file is pointless ([as I've suggested before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148007/sort-contents-of-input-file-and-writing-output-file/54149370#54149370)). Just process all the data in memory before writing it to your output file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use LWP::Simple;

my $dateField = 'date=2018-12-31';
my $currency  = "USD";
my $filename = 'doc3.txt';
my $address = "https://www.oanda.com/rates/api/v1/rates/$currency.csv?"
            . "api_key=gpolonsky&decimal_places=4&$dateField&fields=averages&"
            . "quote=USD&quote=AUD&quote=BRL&quote=CAD&quote=GBP&"
            . "quote=CHF&quote=CNY&quote=DKK&quote=HKD&quote=INR&"
            . "quote=IDR&quote=ILS&quote=JPY&quote=MXN&quote=NOK&"
            . "quote=PHP&quote=PLN&quote=SGD&quote=sKK&quote=ZAR&"
            . "quote=KRW&quote=SEK&quote=TWD&quote=THB&quote=EUR&"
            . "quote=MYR&quote=NZD&quote=SAR&quote=TRY&quote=RUB&"
            . "quote=CZK&quote=AED&quote=CLP&quote=EGP&quote=MAD&"
            . "quote=NGN&quote=OMR&quote=QAR";

my $content = get($address);

# I've removed $! from the die() error below. $! is the last
# *operating system* error. And making an HTTP request is not
# an operating system operation - so the contents will have no
# connection to the results of our GET request.
defined $content or die "Cannot read '$address'";
$content =~  s/^[^\n]*\n//s;
$content =~  s/^/20181231,/gm; # The m option makes ^ match at the start of each line
$content =~  s/,2018-12-3[0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\+0000*//g;
$content =~  s/([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]),[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/$1/g;

my @curOrd = qw( USD AUD BRL GBP CAD CNY DKK HKD INR IDR ILS JPY MXN
                 NOK PHP PLN SGD SKK ZAR KRW SEK CHF TWD THB EUR MYR
                 NZD SAR TRY RUB CZK AED CLP EGP MAD NGN OMR QAR );

my $i = 1;
my %curr_lookup = map { $_ => $i++ } @curOrd;

my @data = map { [ split /,/ ] } split /\n/, $content;

my $outfile = 'file2.txt';

@data = sort { $curr_lookup{$a->[2]} <=> $curr_lookup{$b->[2]} }
        @data;

open my $out, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile for writing: $!";

say $out join ',', @$_ for @data;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to close $file after you fetch the data from the server and are writing it to a file:

```
open(my $file, '>', $filename) or die $!;
print $file $string;
close($file)  # Add this line
```

I also had to use http:// instead of https:// in $address, but I'm on a CentOS box with an old LWP install that doesn't seem to do TLS.